# silently ignore duplicate entries on inserting into database Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, insert, duplicates

I m using zend framework and want to insert data in mysql data base. The program throws error while it encountered row that already exist in database. How to simply ignore the duplicate data and proceed to the next row. Is there any way such as insert ignore in Zend framework?
I could not find exact answer to this question in the web

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to wrap the insert into an Try/Catch Block, something like this:

```
try {
   $db->insert(array());
} catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
  // ignored 
}
```

Better would be to check if the exception if thrown becuase an unique violation, if not throw an new Exception to get the "other" errors.

Other Solutions "expensive because you have to quest the db first"

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'database_table',
        'field' => 'your_field_to_check_for_unique'
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid('your_field_to_check_for_unique) {
         // DO Insert
}
```

Comment: thanks, this catches the error, do you have any idea whts the error code number of duplicate entries, i m using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a "raw" query.
This is an example how to skip already created records and update specific values:

```
$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)  VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = VALUES(col3)';
$dbAdapter->query($query);
```